# Filters being ignored in jquery-datatables-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have used jquery-datatables-rails to present some information for my index and have added in filters following [this](http://www.enten-itc.ch/fr/posts/add-a-filter-form-to-a-ruby-on-rails-server-side-processing-datatable). However the datatable appears to be ignoring the filters and they are not shown as part of the requested json in the get request.

I've enclosed my index method, the datatables class, my index view and the coffeescript I'm running.

Index Method

```
  def index
    @sbcons = Subcontractor.scoped
    if filters = params[:filter]
      @sbcons = @sbcons.where(sbcon_type: filters[:type]) unless filters[:type].blank?
      @sbcons = @sbcons.where(cscs_card: filters[:cscs]) unless filters[:cscs].blank?
      @sbcons = @sbcons.where(approved_status: filters[:approved]) unless filters[:approved].blank?
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons)
      end
    end
  end
```

Index View

```
<% provide(:title, 'All Subcontractors') %>
<h1>Subcontractors List</h1>
<div class="filter">
  <%= form_tag(method: :get, id: "filter_form") do %>
    <%= label_tag :sbcon_type, "Type" %>
    <%= select_tag "filter[type]", options_for_select([[],["Labour Only"], ["Specialist"], ["Both"]]) %>
    <%= label_tag :cscs_card, "CSCS" %>
    <%= select_tag "filter[cscs]", options_for_select([[],["Yes"], ["No"]]) %>
    <%= label_tag :approved_status, "Approved Status" %>
    <%= select_tag "filter[approved]", options_for_select([[],["Approved"], ["Not Approved"]]) %> <br>
    <%= link_to "Filter", '#', id: "filterbutton", class: "btn btn-mini" %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
</div>
<table id="subcontractors" class="table table-condensed table-hover display" data-source="<%= subcontractors_url(format: "json") %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Contact Number</th>
      <th>CSCS</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Scotland</th>
      <th>NE England</th>
      <th>NW England</th>
      <th>Midlands</th>
      <th>SE England</th>
      <th>SW England</th>
      <th>London</th>
      <th>Wales</th>
      <th>Operatives</th>
      <th>Product Liability</th>
      <th>Employer Liability</th>
      <th>Public Liability</th>
      <th>Contractors All Risk</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= javascript_tag do %> 
  $('#filterbutton').click(function (){
    $('#subcontractors').dataTable().fnDraw();
  });
<% end %>
```

Datatables class

```
class SubcontractorsDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, to: :@view

  def initialize(view, sbcons)
    @view = view
    @sbcons = sbcons
  end

  def as_json(option = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Subcontractor.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: subcontractors.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private
  def data
    subcontractors.map do |subcontractor|
      [
        link_to(subcontractor.sbcon_name, subcontractor),
        h(subcontractor.con_tel_num),
        h(subcontractor.cscs_card),
        h(subcontractor.sbcon_type),
        h(subcontractor.scot),
        h(subcontractor.ne_eng),
        h(subcontractor.nw_eng),
        h(subcontractor.mid),
        h(subcontractor.se_eng),
        h(subcontractor.sw_eng),
        h(subcontractor.ldn),
        h(subcontractor.wales),
        h(subcontractor.op_avail),
        h(subcontractor.ins_prod),
        h(subcontractor.ins_emp),
        h(subcontractor.ins_pub),
        h(subcontractor.ins_con_all),
        h(subcontractor.approved_status)
      ]
    end
  end

  def subcontractors
    @subcontractors ||= fetch_subcontractors
  end

  def fetch_subcontractors
    subcontractors = Subcontractor.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    subcontractors = subcontractors.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      subcontractors = subcontractors.where("sbcon_name like :search or con_tel_num like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    subcontractors
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[sbcon_name con_tel_num cscs_card sbcon_type scot ne_eng nw_eng mid se_eng sw_eng lon wales op_avail ins_prod ins_emp ins_pub ins_con_all approved_status]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

Coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
        $('#subcontractors').dataTable
          sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
          sdom: "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
          bProcessing: true
          bServerSide: true
          sAjaxSource: $('#subcontractors').data('source')
          fnServerParams: (aoData) ->
              for form_element in $('#filter_form').serializeArray()
                aoData.push
                  name: form_element.name
                  value: form_element.value
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, are you using pry to debug this?

Comment: No I wasn't even sure where to start looking, I can't work out why it's skipping the filtering step.

Comment: Well, in this case I usually throw a binding.pry into various places and see where it isn't being triggered

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger ... add gem "pry" and gem "pry-debugger" .. then bundle.. then restart server.. then add binding.pry anywhere in your code and when the server hits the binding.pry it will stop and you can interact with an irb console within your environment... try adding that in places you expect it to be called, and you might find your problem. Don't forget to check your server console for the pry irb once you reload the page with binding.pry triggered

Comment: for example, you could test that if filters = params[:filter] is true by placing 'binding.pry' just below if filters = params[:filter] and seeing if your page load hangs. If it does, you're sorted.. check your server console.. if not.. well, if filters = params[:filter] was false

Comment: It definitely isn't hanging at the filters part, I'm not sure why that isn't working though

Comment: Well once you enter your irb console inside of if filters.. try running @sbcons = @sbcons.where(sbcon_type: filters[:type]) unless filters[:type].blank? and see if you get any errors

Comment: I just stepped through it having removed the if block from the filters area and it returned `NoMethodError (undefined method []' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/subcontractors_controller.rb:31:in index'` which means the filters are returning as nil even if they have data in them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31390/discussion-between-abram-and-ryanmacg)

Comment: Hey do you need to put @sbcons = @sbcons.where(sbcon_type: params[:filters][:type]) unless params[:filters][:type].blank?

Comment: I've added an answer below based on our discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Abram's suggesting I looked through if filters part and found that it was never being called. I fixed this by amending the form_tag as follows:

```
<%= form_tag('#', method: :get, id: "filter_form") do %>
```

From here I found that the filters were being passed but ignored. Abram suggested moving the logic to the fetch_subcontractors method in the datatables class and changed the initalize method at the same time to reflect this

```
def initialize(view, subcontractors)
    @view = view
  end
def fetch_subcontractors
    subcontractors = Subcontractor.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    subcontractors = subcontractors.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      subcontractors = subcontractors.where("sbcon_name like :search or con_tel_num like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    if filters = params[:filter]
      binding.pry
      subcontractors = subcontractors.where(sbcon_type: filters[:type]) unless filters[:type].blank?
      subcontractors = subcontractors.where(cscs_card: filters[:cscs]) unless filters[:cscs].blank?
      subcontractors = subcontractors.where(approved: filters[:approved]) unless filters[:approved].blank?
    end
    subcontractors
  end
```

with these corrections the filters work properly and display the correct results.

Comment: hey just want to make sure that everything else is working, like your searching and ordering?

Comment: I have a feeling looking at the above that if you have a search term and a filter the filter will override the search term.. correct me if I'm wrong. I hope I am!

Comment: They work fine, I thought it would cause issues too but thankfully not

Comment: Awesome, impressive scoping.